# Missed calls appearing on two different phones

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, phone.app

One of my phones is an iPhone SE and another an iPhone 5S.

When you go to phone.app -> Recents the same calls appear on both devices.

They are both on the same Apple ID so this is probably why.

In iCloud Settings I found no option to disable this.

How can this be stopped without changing Apple ID's on one device?

Comment: You have the obvious solution, why not apply it?

Comment: @SolarMike What do you mean? I said I don’t want them to be on separate accounts. And I don’t want to disable it

Comment: What I meant is clear. Both phones are doing what is required by showing a missed call.

Comment: @SolarMike and my question is how can I disable it

Comment: Do they both have the same phone number?  I thought 'Rececents' only listed calls to a specific phone number.

Comment: @fsb different phone numbers

Comment: The only fix is to log out of iCloud drive on the secondary device.  I did some more research on this and everything said this is the only way to fix it.

Comment: @fsb ok thanks, could you turn it into an answer with references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by sharing the same Apple ID on both devices.

According to [this](https://iphone-tricks.com/tutorial/3506-fix-for-recent-calls-appearing-on-another-iphone), [this](http://innov8tiv.com/fix-call-history-is-showing-up-on-other-iphones-why-recent-calls-appearing-on-other-iphones/), and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7053494) sites, you can either

1. Create a separate Apple ID for one of the phones, or
2. Turn off `Settings -> (Your Apple ID) -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive`:

[image]

Comment: Will turning off iCloud Drive have any other effects?

Comment: This may give you an idea : https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19386?locale=en_US